# Change the color of a link using the ribbon in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

A user pasted the content from a word document into a wiki page.
In the word document all the links have the same font and color but on the wiki page some links are blue, some black, some using arial, some using times new roman. I guess the generated HTML screwed it up. Anyhow, when I mark text I can change the color, font, size and so on but when I mark a link the change color button is disabled (but I can change font and size), why is this? Do I need to ask the user to copy the contect back to a word document, edit there and then copy paste it again to the wiki?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that there is some embedded css styles in the text that was pasted which is what is causing you grief.  There should be a button that you can use to edit the raw html to get rid of those styles.  Otherwise it is helpful if people paste unstyled text i.e. As Text.. rather the styled As HTML.. text.